# Calculate direction vector given variable hypotenuse in orbital path

Tags: unity-game-engine, math, trigonometry

[image]

In a Unity 3D game I'm trying to make an object (D) orbit another object (B) and draw a ray between another object positioned above the object being orbited (A) and the orbiting object, essentially describing a triangle (or cone, given time + orbit speed):

The object conforms to a hilly terrain (moves up or down from height B as it orbits) via some unrelated code, however, this sometimes means it is positioned further away than max length, for example if it travels down a steep valley or up a steep hill higher than A.

The difficulty I'm having is calculating the vector to the furthest point on the terrain allowed by max length from transform A. To put it another way - in the illustration above the final direction line is the max length line rotated around A until it hits the terrain, this is what I'm after regardless of the height or angle of the terrain.

My trigonometry is pretty basic but I thought calculating the angle from the tangent of AC and AB then multiplying its quaternion by the directional vector (c - a) would give the right direction from A. This is the code on the orbiting object D:

```
private void Update()
{
    transform.RotateAround(transformB.position, Vector3.up, rotSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -transform.up, out hit, 100))
    {
        float angleDeg = Mathf.Atan2(transformA.position.y, 
            Vector3.Distance(hit.point, transformA.position)) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

        Quaternion q = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angleDeg, Vector3.left);

        Vector3 dir = q * (new Vector3(hit.point.x, transformA.position.y, 
            hit.point.z) - transformA.position);

        Debug.DrawRay(firingTransform.position, dir, Color.green, 0.1f);

    }
}
```

It seems to work correctly for only half of the orbit:

[image]

I've tried various vectors for `Quaternion.AngleAxis` axis parameter.

Comment: Could you please explain what your code does (or is supposed to do)? Is `transform` the transform of `D`? Do you simply want a ray from `A` to the vertical projection of `D` onto the terrain? If you want to find the radius such that the hypothenuse is of a given length, it is not enough to have a single height sample.

Comment: Why do you need to calculate the angle in the first place? What you script is doing right now is: Cast a ray from A toward its `-transform.up` direction. Then you calculate the angle of the ray you just cast (which is arbitrary, since it depends on the orientation of A). Then you calculate another vector going from A to hit and rotate it by that angle. Why not just `Debug.DrawRay(transformA.position, hit.point-transformA.position, Color.green, 0.1f);` without the steps inbetween?

Comment: @NicoSchertler I hadn't thought about it that way but computing the radius would allow me to solve the problem another way using the methods built into the game engine. What else is required to compute it? Yes, transform in the code is the transform of D.

Comment: @AliBaba The ray is cast from the orbiting object downwards. Due to the terrain the hit point may be further way than max dist.

Comment: @Absinthe The only way I could think of to achieve what you want would be to do multiple ray casts from `A` at different angles. Let's say you start at 10°, cast a ray and check the distance between `hít` and `A`. If the distance is smaller than `maxlength`, cast a ray at 20°, then at 30°,40° and so on. If the distance is greater than `maxlength`, cast a ray at 35°,then 32,5° or 37.5° ect. Do this until you are close enough to `maxlength` or until the change in angle gets too small

Comment: Is your terrain a height field over a (uniform) grid?

Comment: @ Nico Its a mix of many seperate meshes. Its not grid based.

Comment: Then I fear I don't see any more efficient option than what Ali suggested, i.e. sample a couple different angles and measure the distance. Essentially, you want to perform line search. One possibility that could make this faster is to assume that nearby directions have similar radii, so you can start your line search there as initial guess.